# How to test whether the simulated mean differs from observed mean?

Tags: r, time-series, hypothesis-testing, bootstrap, permutation-test

I have three log-return time series `data1`, the data look like:

```
head(data1)
#              r1           r2         r3
#[1,]  0.09251185  0.079745597  0.130000000
#[2,] -0.08814853  0.005890349 -0.053097345
#[3,] -0.02378687 -0.003603604  0.046728972
#[4,]  0.04902534  0.030289331 -0.005952381
#[5,]  0.03669981  0.008336990  0.017964072
#[6,] -0.03298082 -0.130113142 -0.102941176
```

Each log-return time series is not normal and correlated each other.
r_i, i=1,2,..., are dependently and not-identically distributed but have finite four moments. The length of r_i, i=1, 2,... is above 500 items.

I have applied a model and compute the mean vector `model_mu2`:

```
# [1] 0.007744681 0.013342437 0.012513445
```

I need to know, whether the simulated mean (**not median**) differs from observed mean (two-tailed test)?

**Question.** What a test one can use to test whether the simulated mean differs from the observed mean?

**My attempt for the first column is**

```
wilcox.test(data1[,1], alternative = "two.sided",
             mu = model_mu2[1], conf.int = TRUE)

        Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction

data:  data1[, 1]
V = 53332, p-value = 4.664e-05
alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 0.007744681
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.002419831  0.004090282
sample estimates:
(pseudo)median 
  0.0008300681
```

The returned p-value = 4.664e-05 less 0.05 and we should reject the H0.

Comment: A Wilcoxon signed rank test is not a test of means. It also assumes independence, which you (presumably) won't have.

Comment: Thank you comment. How to test mean vector in my case? Monte Carlo?

Comment: A permutation test of a difference in means would be my first thought (which would only need exchangeability under the null). If samples are not small, perhaps a bootstrap test instead.

Comment: However, those only work if the assumption of independence (or at the least, exchangeability) holds, which is not generally the case with time series variables.